# Excel table filter for specific date and unique dates

Tags: excel, date, filtering

Trying to filter a table to show the associated data for the unique dates of a specific day of the week.

Managed to filter the table for a desired day of the week using a dropdown.
=FILTER(FILTER(Member, Member[Day]=H1),{0,0,1,1,1,1},"No results")

Can filter unique dates from the table.
=unique(Member[date])

Struggling to combine the two together.

[image: Data Table and filter]

Any help would be appreciated.
If more info is needed, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some sample data using [Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) and show expected output as well.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, however, what I have tried and came up with the following two ways, may be one of the other satisfies your requirements.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:F27,
     _Day, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _Dates, INDEX(_Data,,3),
     DROP(FILTER(_Data,(MAP(_Dates,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(C2:x,x)))=1)*(H1=_Day)),,2))
```

---

The above formula returns only the first occurrences of the dates, I am not sure how you can combine `UNIQUE()` with `FILTER()` function as the data does not have duplicates other than the dates and days.

---

Another one which I can think of is:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:F27,
     _Day, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _Dates, INDEX(_Data,,3),
     _Transform, HSTACK(TAKE(_Data,,2),TEXT(MAP(_Dates,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(C2:x,x))),"[=1]#;;")*_Dates,DROP(_Data,,3)),
     IFERROR(DROP(FILTER(_Transform, _Day=H1),,2),""))
```

---

**Note:** Again, I might have not understood the expected output you would need, it is quite possible to make the required changes, if explained more and shown with adequate data.

---